# Database scheme for tree comments

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

What is the best way to implement tree comments (each comment can have comments, those comments can have comments too).
It should be up to 10 levels of comments.

I'm using Rails with PostgreSQL database.

The obvious way is to do this like

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :comment
```

But I assume there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to organize ActiveRecord model into a tree structure. 
Try [Ancestry Gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) (or other similar)
Also, [Railscast: Trees with Ancestry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry)